# Airflow's BashOperator cannot launch docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have this Airflow Task that must run `docker-compose`.

The command below works perfectly well alone as the airflow user.

`docker-compose -f /home/airflow/update-scraping/docker-compose.yml up --build`

But when I wrap it in a BashOperator I got this error :

```
[2021-01-27 23:32:13,903] {taskinstance.py:901} INFO - Executing <Task(BashOperator): update-scraping> on 2021-01-27T23:27:05.828047+00:00
[2021-01-27 23:32:13,905] {standard_task_runner.py:54} INFO - Started process 111626 to run task
[2021-01-27 23:32:13,944] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'run', 'update-scraping', 'update-scraping', '2021-01-27T23:27:05.828047+00:00', '--job_id', '99', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '-sd', 'DAGS_FOLDER/update-scraping.py', '--cfg_path', '/tmp/tmpoo___wh5']
[2021-01-27 23:32:13,945] {standard_task_runner.py:78} INFO - Job 99: Subtask update-scraping
[2021-01-27 23:32:13,996] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: update-scraping.update-scraping 2021-01-27T23:27:05.828047+00:00 [running]> on host ip-10-0-149-233.eu-west-3.compute.internal
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,071] {bash_operator.py:113} INFO - Tmp dir root location: 
 /tmp
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,072] {bash_operator.py:134} INFO - Temporary script location: /tmp/airflowtmpxdo3epew/update-scrapingsmc6tuxa
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,072] {bash_operator.py:146} INFO - Running command: docker-compose -f /home/airflow/update-scraping/docker-compose.yml up --build
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,079] {bash_operator.py:153} INFO - Output:
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,619] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - [111632] Failed to execute script docker-compose
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 727, in urlopen
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/util/retry.py", line 410, in increment
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/packages/six.py", line 734, in reraise
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 677, in urlopen
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 392, in _make_request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1277, in request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "http/client.py", line 972, in send
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,620] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/api/client.py", line 214, in _retrieve_server_version
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/api/client.py", line 237, in _get
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "requests/sessions.py", line 543, in get
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "requests/sessions.py", line 530, in request
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "requests/sessions.py", line 643, in send
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - 
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker-compose", line 3, in <module>
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 80, in main
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/main.py", line 189, in perform_command
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/command.py", line 70, in project_from_options
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/command.py", line 153, in get_project
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 43, in get_client
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "compose/cli/docker_client.py", line 170, in docker_client
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/api/client.py", line 197, in __init__
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO -   File "docker/api/client.py", line 222, in _retrieve_server_version
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,621] {bash_operator.py:157} INFO - docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied'))
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,702] {bash_operator.py:159} INFO - Command exited with return code 255
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,718] {taskinstance.py:1150} ERROR - Bash command failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/miniconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/models/taskinstance.py", line 984, in _run_raw_task
    result = task_copy.execute(context=context)
  File "/home/airflow/miniconda3/envs/airflow/lib/python3.9/site-packages/airflow/operators/bash_operator.py", line 165, in execute
    raise AirflowException("Bash command failed")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: Bash command failed
[2021-01-27 23:32:14,720] {taskinstance.py:1187} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=update-scraping, task_id=update-scraping, execution_date=20210127T232705, start_date=20210127T233213, end_date=20210127T233214
[2021-01-27 23:32:18,854] {local_task_job.py:102} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
```

Comment: for the sake of troubleshooting try using  `sudo docker-compose -f /home/airflow/update-scraping/docker-compose.yml up --build` or add the Airflow user to the docker group, and see what you get this time!

Comment: The user was already in the docker group. Adding `echo <pwd> | sudo -S ...` make it work. I'm not confortable to 1) run docker-compose as sudo 2) have writing down the user password in the task command (accessible easily then). And still don't understand why this command on the terminal is working w/o `sudo` but needs it when played by Airflow itself ?

Comment: Which Ariflow version and Executor do you use?

Comment: Last on in the v1 branch so 1.10.14

Comment: Which executor do you use? Is it possible that when execute from terminal you do it from the scheduler machine but the operator is actually executed on worker machine with different permissions?